# Return larger value of tuple

Tags: list, recursion, sml, mode, ml

I'm trying to find the Mode of a list, and return a tuple of the mode, and the number of times it occurs in the list.
I have it to a point where I can return a list of each number and the number of times it occurs after that, but it also gives me occurrences past the first,

```
fun counter(_, nil) = 0
  | counter(a, x::xs) = if a = x then 1+counter(a, xs)
            else counter(a, xs);

fun countList(nil) = []
  | countList(x::xs) =
    (x, counter(x, x::xs))::countList(xs);

val lst = countList([1,2,1,1,3,4,5,2,1,2,1]);
```

Gives me val lst = [(1,5),(2,3),(1,4),(1,3),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1),(2,2),(1,2),(2,1),(1,1)]
  : (int * int) list

Which shouldn't be a problem, just loop through each value and see if the first values equal and then only give the first value, then only return the greatest one(s) but I cant seem to be able to figure that part out. 
I guess I'm just having trouble looping through the list and compare to the current value that I'm checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you computed `lst` list, you don't need to find matching elements in it. The only thing you need to do is to traverse the list to find the element with maximum tuple second value.

```
fun findMax l =
  let fun find (nil, acc) = acc
  | find ((value, count)::xs, (acc_value, acc_count)) =
    if count > acc_count then find (xs, (value, count))
    else if value = acc_value then (acc_value, acc_count)
    else find (xs, (acc_value, acc_count))
  in find (l, (0, 0)) end;

findMax lst;
val it = (1, 5): int * int
```

However, this solution has O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity. Alternatively, you can sort elements first in O(n * log n) time, and then return the first element (or several ones) from the list with maximum number of occurrences.

Comment: This works great, now I just need to figure out how to adapt this to return a list, because if there are two values that occur the most but have the same number of occurrences, I need both of those values in a list.